# Pushing Into a Sorted Queue Implementation

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement a method that no matter what order the data is inserted into the queue, it will be sorted. For example, my main has this to test the method:

```
OrderedQueue ordQueue;
    ordQueue.push(2);
    ordQueue.push(1);
    ordQueue.push(3);
    ordQueue.display();
```

It should output: 1, 2, 3. But there is something wrong with my push method. How should I be organizing the data?

```
 void OrderedQueue::push(int item)
{
    if (IsEmpty())
        front = rear = new ListQueueNode(item);
    else
    {
        ListQueueNode *here = front;
        ListQueueNode *ptr = rear->next = new ListQueueNode(item);

        while (here!=NULL){
             if (item < here->value){
                 front->next = front;
                 front = ptr;
            }
             else if (item > here->value){
                 rear = ptr;
             }
             here = here->next;
        }

    }
    count++;
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using `std::priority_queue`? It does pretty much what you want. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue

Comment: I did look into that, but apparently we need to use this method instead. It's for a class, so we need to inherit from other classes.

Comment: sorted queue looks like a misnomer, queue is a data structure used for keeping elements based on their insertion order, not their values

Comment: Here's a tip, take a pencil and paper, draw some boxes for the nodes, and try to insert a new value onto the queue by following the code.

Comment: Are you allowed to change the code? I would have a member vector and call sort after a push_back in push.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should clear about pushing situation:

- new element was push to queue as first item
- other

So you should change your code:

```
void OrderedQueue::push(int item)
{
    if (IsEmpty())
        front = rear = new ListQueueNode(item);
    else
    {
        ListQueueNode here = front;
        ListQueueNode prev = NULL;
        ListQueueNode ptr = new ListQueueNode(item);

        while (here != NULL  && item < here.value) {
            prev = here;
            here = here.next;
        }

        if (prev == NULL) {  // push new element as the first item
            ptr.next = front;
            front = ptr;
        } else {  // other
            prev.next = ptr;
            ptr.next = here;
        }
    }
    count++;
}
```

Follow this code: rear contain min value in queue, front contain max value in queue. You can change `item > here.value` to change order of queue.